# Can't log in. Log in button missing

Tags: wp-login-form

I have uploaded the WordPress files from local to the main server using FileZilla. The front end of the site works fine but when trying to login into back end using `sitename/wp-admin`, it shows the log in page with no log in button. I have uploaded an image for reference.

Some steps I have followed:

1. Re-uploaded the files - Not resolved.
2. Checked the `wp-config.php` file - Not resolved.
3. Checked in multiple browsers - Same issue.

Any help, hacks, or turnarounds would be very helpful.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps there is an error occurring at a certain point which is causing only a portion of the page to render. https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress

Comment: It works without any issues in local server and even debug options doesnt show anything ? Does it have anything to do with the configuration or version of the wordpress ?

Comment: @DaveRomsey anything else that might be causing this like files getting corrupted or data in the tables getting corrupted ?

Comment: I doubt it's an issue with the version of WP. You could try renaming the plugins dir temporarily to disable all of them. I find it odd that no errors are being reported or logged though. Really, tough to say with only a screen shot.

Comment: In order to administer a WordPress site, the site owner must log in. When logged in, WordPress makes the log in button disappear. i.e log in is only visible for visitors who are not already logged in. Some people don't realise this and look at their site (when logged in), and then look at the theme demo (when not logged in), pick up on the difference and see the missing login button as something which needs to be fixed.

Comment: No, this isn't true. I'm signed in to my site, and when I go to `wp-login.php` it displays the login form in its entirety.